# SSRS: Range Bar Chart not displaying repeated status based on Date Range

Tags: reporting-services, charts, stacked-chart, stackedbarseries

I have a query that gives me the daily status of an item based on desired date range (parameters).  This status will vary and can repeat.  For example, it can chronologically be: Operational, Repair, Inspection, Operational, Inspection.  As you can see Operational & Inspection are represented twice but at different times.  While this is true, I cannot seem to get this represented graphically in a Range Bar Chart because it will only display one instance of each status (as shown in the picture). The picture indicates where the remaining status should be presented.

[Range bar Chart Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frv4Z.png)

The data set I am working with is as follows:

[Range bar Chart Error Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwfFv.png)

As you can see, the chart should represent 4 status in the following order: Inspection, Operational, Repair, Operational but does not display the 2nd Operational status.

Can anyone assist me to overcome this particular hurdle or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction... This is how I would probably approach it.

You need to add an additional column to your dataset. I replicated your dataset into a table variable and then used the following to get the additional column

```
-- this just replicates your data..    
DECLARE @t TABLE(StatusDate DATE, StatType varchar(20), statStart DateTime, statEnd DateTime, StatusDays int)

    INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('2017-02-16', 'Inspection', '2017-01-30 12:49:14', '2017-02-21 12:49:14', 22),
    ...
    ...
    ('2017-03-14', 'Operational', '2017-03-01 11:49:11', '2017-04-19 15:19:48', 49)

-- the important bit    
    SELECT 
        *
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY statStart) as Sort
     FROM @t
```

This gives us the following output.

[image]

We can use this extra field in SSRS to group and sort the data correctly.

[image]

I then used the following expression for the chart series color property to make sure that the colours are consistent with the statType

```
=SWITCH(
    Fields!StatType.Value = "Inspection", "Tan",
    Fields!StatType.Value = "Operational", "Green",
    Fields!StatType.Value = "Repair", "Red",
    True, "Blue"
    )
```

(the Blue line is there in case we are missing a type, it'll show on the chart n blue.)

This gives us..
[image]

Hopefully that will give you enough to go on.

Comment: Thank you Alan!  I am going to go and try this.  If it works as I need it to, then I will be back to confirm and mark your answer.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!  Your solution (The Dense_Rank) solved my issues. Much appreciated.